# String is not getting encoded properly written in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, encoding, utf-8

My application is built in Angular 7 with Typescript.

I have the following code in typescript file.

```
this.confirmationDialogService.confirm(null, 'er du sikker på, at du vil gøre denne ændring', "Acceptere", "Afvise")
```

But, when I publish it, the string is not getting encoded and rendered properly in browser.

```
this.confirmationDialogService.confirm(null, 'er du sikker p�, at du vil g�re denne �ndring', "Acceptere", "Afvise")
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "./src", "manager/IocDataMapperModule.cs", "../TV2.DataLayer/IUserSkillDataLayer.cs", "../TV2.DataLayer.Mongo/UserSkillDataLayer.cs"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./scripts/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "charset": "utf8",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Several things can go wrong and need to be checked:

- Your text editor might use ISO-8851-1 encoding but your config file instructs Typescript to treat it as Unicode. Check the encoding in your text editor.
- Your web server might be configured incorrectly. Use an inspector in your browser, record the network request and check that the main HTML file uses UTF-8. One of the response headers should be: `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: I have enabled the "Advance Save Options" in the Visual Studio's File Menu and changed the Encoding to `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001` and now it is working. But, I don't understand why it is necessary?

Comment: The source code you write has an encoding too. And like all other text files the encoding is not saved in the file itself. So when the Typescript compiler reads the source code, it needs to be told the encoding. You have declared that the encoding of the Typescript input files is "utf8". So you need to save them as such. The other option is that you change the compiler option to `charset": "iso-8859-1"`. As far as I understand, the output files of the Typescript compiler are alsways in UTF-8.

Comment: It's still a bit tricky to find the save with encoding option in Visual Studio 2022:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2022
It did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to use i18n from angular. Here is the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/i18n , and set the locale of you app to the location you need.

Comment: *i18n* is about translating text, dates etc. It has nothing to do with text encoding, UTF-8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the web server you can use the `charset` attribute in your `<script>` tag.

`<script src="Script.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

I had to do this when I was trying to run HTML & JavaScript directly from a `file:` URL.